# Loop the second list based on the first list

Tags: scala, loops, dictionary

I got two lists `l1` and `l2` , based on the `l1` , `l2` need to be looped.

```
val l1 = List("a", "b")
val l2 = List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
```

I tried like this, but not getting the right result

```
l1.map { x =>
  l2.map { y =>
    println(x, y)
  }
}
```

Result got

```
(a,1)
(a,2)
(a,3)
(a,4)
(a,5)
```

Here `l2` is looping until the end of items in that list, but I want it to loop only once for each item in `l1` and for the second item in the `l1` , `l2` need to be looped again for once but with the next item in the list.

Result expected

```
(a,1)
(b,2)
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `zip` to do this:

```
l1 zip l2
```